# Wanting to create an java servlet / jsp website that connects to IBM Connections using OAuth/OAuth2 or something else, Where to begin?

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, ibm-connections

I currently have an account on IBM Connections. My goal is to make a website that (preferably) uses OAuth or OAuth2 yet I have no idea where to start. And after trying to find out how for 2/3 hours I am at a loss. Can't find a single decent tutorial. So my question is: How can I link my servlet application to my( or someone else who logs in) connections account?

Comment: This project may help -https://github.com/ibmcnxdev/photosharing-java and this doc - https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Dev+Guide+topics#action=openDocument&res_title=Understanding_OAuth_2.0&content=sdkcontent

Comment: thanks a lot. This really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Connetions contains an OAuth provider. Here is the link: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_general_policyset.html

Comment: by implication, I think the author is asking about IBM Connections Cloud.  It is best to reference the links I mentioned above.